# How to set environment variables for complex configuration parameters in AWS lambda using asp.net core 3.1 serverless?

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-sam

In my **asp.net core 3.1** web API `launchsettings.json` I have a environment variable named `"AdminstratorConfig:AdminstratorPassword": "myPasswordValue"`

Now in my code I also have a class named `AppSettings` defined like this:

```
public class AppSettings
{
    public AdminstratorConfiguration AdminstratorConfig { get; set; }
}

public class AdminstratorConfiguration
{
    public string AdminstratorPassword { get; set; }
}
```

When running in my **local** I can bind the environment variable into my **AppSettings** instance using something like this in the `Startup`

```
public class Startup
{

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        var appSettings = new AppSettings();
        Configuration.Bind(appSettings);
        // Here appSettings.AdminstratorConfig.AdminstratorPassword contains value 'myPasswordValue' 
    }
}
```

I cal also load the same from my appsettings.json if I have my configuration defined as

```
{
   "AdminstratorConfig": 
    {
       "AdminstratorPassword": "myPasswordValue"
    }
}
```

However after deploying my application as AWS serverless lambda I tried to set the same environment variable in Lambda configuration section but it doesn't allow special characters here ' **:** '

Is there a way we can set and load these complex environment variables in AWS Lambda similar to my local?
if not what are the possible alternate approaches?

Comment: Refer to this article, which may help:https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/net-core-3-0-on-lambda-with-aws-lambdas-custom-runtime/

Comment: Please add to your question your aws sam template file

Answer (score 2):

You can use `__` (double underscore) instead of `:` (colon), so the environment variable in lambda would be `AdministratorConfig__AdministratorPassword` as the key and your `myPasswordValue` as the value.

See the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-7.0#configuration-keys-and-values).